# Azure devOps wiki: create tables microsoft docs style

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-wiki

How to create tables on Azure Devops wiki with the same appearences as Microsoft's ?

[image]

right now I'm using this pattern, but would like to use the same style that Microsoft uses for its docs.

```
|H1|H2| 
|-|-| 
|Content|
```

results to ==>

| H1 | H2 |
| --- | --- |
| Content |  |

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> How to create tables on Azure Devops wiki with the same appearences as Microsoft's ?

You could try to use HTML tables on Azure devops Wiki:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>H1</td>
    <td>H2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">content</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

[image]

Comment: Can the cell content be code snippets enclosed in triple \`\`\`?

Answer (score 2):

I dont think thats possible.
The Wiki is mainly driven by Markdown, so everythin you want to do needs to be possible in [Markdown](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/project/wiki/wiki-markdown-guidance?view=azure-devops)